# How can I block the ip address with https in IIS or Windows Server?

Tags: ssl, iis, https, url-rewrite-module, iis-8.5

I am getting this not secure error and not found for an IP address domain.  How can I tell this to not be requested at all?

[image]

Comment: Run a report on each of the sites, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html and then you know what are the correct URLs for them. To learn why a site is not secure, however, you need to run another report, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: I need to know why the IP is being hit for the server and trying to serve up a page.

Comment: No one here can answer that without knowing what is the IP you typed in the address bar and what are the IP addressed bind to this server. The network administrators are usually involved in such investigation.

Comment: If I provided the actually IP then you can tell me how to shut it down where the server doesnt have access?  I have another server where it says "the site cant be reached", but no idea why using just the IP.  I want to do the same here on this server.